# Handling international dates in python

Tags: python, datetime, internationalization, locale

I have a date that is either in German for e.g,

```
2. Okt. 2009
```

and also perhaps as

```
2. Oct. 2009
```

How do I convert this into an ISO datetime (or Python `datetime`)?

Solved by using this snippet:

```
for l in locale.locale_alias:
    worked = False
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, l)
        worked = True
    except:
        worked = False
    if worked: print l
```

And then plugging in the appropriate for the parameter l in `setlocale`.

Can parse using

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.strptime("09. Okt. 2009", "%d. %b. %Y")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html

The `datetime` module is already locale-aware.

It's something like the following

```
# German locale
loc = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, ("de","de"))
try:
     date = datetime.date.strptime(input, "%d. %b. %Y")
except:
     # English locale
     loc = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, ("en","us"))
     date = datetime.date.strptime(input, "%d. %b. %Y")
```

Comment: thanks. I had to search for supported locales on my machine (see edit) to find the appropriate German locale identifier.

Comment: `type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime'` (neither in 2.7 nor in 3.5). Use `datetime.strptime()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Very minor point about your code snippet: I'm no Python expert but I'd consider the whole "flag to check for success + silently swallowing all exceptions" to be bad style.

`try/expect/else` does what you want in a cleaner way, I think:

```
for l in locale.locale_alias:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, l)
    except locale.Error: # the doc says setlocale should throw this on failure
        pass
    else:
        print l
```